# how do I differentiate between str and int and is this what ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: error means?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
   choice = input (" ")
   choice = int(choice)
    if choice == 2:
        print ("What class are you in? Please choose (class) 1, 2 or 3.")
        Class = int(input ())

        #class 1 file
        if Class == 1:
            c1 = open('class1.csv', 'a+')
            ScoreCount = str(ScoreCount)
            c1.write(myName + "-"  + ScoreCount)
            c1.write("\n")
            c1.close()

            read_c1 = open('class1.csv', 'r')
            print (read_c1)


    if choice == 3:
        row[1]=int(row[1]) #converts the values into int.
        row[2]=int(row[2])
        row[3]=int(row[3])
        row[4]=int(row[4])

    if choice == 4:
        WMCI= 1
        print ("Thank You. Bye!")
```

So when this code is actually run it outputs an error which I don't understand:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:#(myName-score)

How to fix this and what does this error mean in simple terms?

Comment: Can you point out which part of the code is actually raising the error?

Comment: What did you put in the inputs?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That includes removing any noise that we don't care about (input, printing, irrelevant stuff to the error) and hardcore and values necessary to reproduce the error. And show us the full traceback.

Comment: '    for row in csv_c1:
                newlist.append(row[0:5])
                row[0] = int (row[0])
                row[1] = int (row[1])
                row[2] = int (row[2])'

Comment: plus, you mean the noise YOU don't care about. Others manage to help spot other things that are wrong and are in need of being modified - see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 2 bugs.
The first is when you store your score into the csv, you're converting ScoreCount into a string, and keeping it that way. You need to let the conversion be temporary for just the job:

```
    #class 1 file
    if Class == 1:
        c1 = open('class1.csv', 'a+')
        c1.write(myName + "-"  + str(ScoreCount))
        c1.write("\n")
        c1.close()

        read_c1 = open('class1.csv', 'r')
        print (read_c1)
```

That'll fix it with Class 1, you'll need to do 2 & 3. Your second bug is when you're reading the scores from the file, you've stored them as: "Name-5" if the person called Name had scored 5. That means you can't convert them as a whole entity into a number. You'll need to split the number part off. So in min max, where you've got:

```
row[0] = int (row[0])
```

It needs to become:

```
row[0] = int(row[0].split("-")[1])
```

But from there I can't figure out your logic or what you're trying to achieve in that section of code. It'll get rid of the current error, but that part of your code needs more work.

Explaining the right hand side of the above line of code by building it up:

```
row[0]  # For our example, this will return 'Guido-9'
row[0].split("-")  # Splits the string to return ['Guido','9']
row[0].split("-")[1]  # Takes the second item and returns '9'
int(row[0].split("-")[1])  # Turns it into a number and returns 9
```

split("-") is the part you're likely to not have met, it breaks a string up into a list, splitting it at the point of the "-" in our example, but would be at the spaces if the brackets were left empty: split() or any other character you put in the brackets.

Comment: hi paul could you please explain the coding for the row bit plz (the one you did - and also plz explain what I was doing wrong so that this can be a learning experience for me) . p.s. do you teach gcse or higher level?

Comment: I'll edit the code above to show what each part of the right hand side returns. At the moment I'm only teaching to GCSE, but I'm capable of teaching beyond A-Level.

Comment: See, from these rows calculate min, max and average values. That I know how to do. However 1problem remains, if I run the code you've provided it says IndexError: list index out of range. Note: that I am using the above code to read from multiple rows but just changing the no. in the 1st [] and 2nd [] but not the 3 []. This to make sure that the 1st and 2nd [] contain the same no. as they are the numbers that refer to the row (I’m presuming)?                                                                                 i.e. row [1st] = (row[2nd].split(“-“)[3rd]) Why does that keep appearing?

Comment: I have made changes to the file as well just as you suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but for multiple rows: row[1] = int(row[1].split("-")[1]) and row[2] = int(row[2].split("-")[1])

Comment: Problem sorted. Found out that it was the tiniest thing stopping me from accomplishing the task! Instead of a - I had use , which allowed the bits of data to be inputted into different cells when I opened up the csv in excel.

From here my original coding should work so I won't have to use the bits provided but thanks for every bit of help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to convert something that can't be converted to an int for example

```
int("h")
```

This would give the base 10 error which you are getting

Comment: '    for row in csv_c1:
                newlist.append(row[0:5])
                row[0] = int (row[0])
                row[1] = int (row[1])
                row[2] = int (row[2])'